# pgfplots histogram with custom symbolic coords

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, coordinates, histogram

I'm trying to modify a simple example of a histogram with symbolic coordinates from the pgfplots 1.14 manual, page 503. This is the example (mwe):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar interval,
        hist/symbolic coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J},
        xticklabel={[\tick--\nexttick]}],
      ]
      \addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
        table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
        data\\
        A\\ B\\ A\\ D\\ F\\ J\\
        G\\ J\\ I\\ H\\ I\\ I\\
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

All I did below was change the letters A-J to lower case:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      ybar interval,
      hist/symbolic coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j},
      xticklabel={[\tick--\nexttick]}],
    ]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
      table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
      data\\
      a\\ b\\ a\\ d\\ f\\ j\\
      g\\ j\\ i\\ h\\ i\\ i\\
      };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in the following error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `a' has not been defined
with 'symbolic hist/data coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J}... Maybe it has been miss
pelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]a?.
```

It seems as if the symbolic coordinates I provide are ignored. 
Indeed, when replacing the line

```
hist/symbolic coords={A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J},
```

with any of the following lines

```
hist/symbolic coords,
hist/symbolic coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j},
hist/symbolic coords={k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t},
```

there is no error.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: I'll consider this as a bug which I have reported [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/134/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because because the bug is solved in PGFPlots v1.15

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. Thanks for the report and thanks for the bug report https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/134/! I will take care of it